# Preventing scaling text while scaling parent div

Tags: javascript, zooming, raphael, scaletransform

Now am working on project of a floor plan map that contains a certain amount of rooms – each room is being represented as a Raphael.js shape, and in the middle of the shape there’s  a number of tasks. Font size No of tasks needs to be fixed for each shape.

For zooming in:

```
(this._zoom <= 6 && this._zoom > 0) ?
(this.count) ? this._textPaperSet.forEach(function (e) {
e.transform("...s" + (1 / defaultZoomStep));
}) : ''
                : '';
```

And zooming out similarly:

```
(this._zoom >= -0.16) ?
(this.count) ? this._textPaperSet.forEach(function (e) {
e.transform("...s" + (1 * defaultZoomStep));
}) : ''
                : '';
```

And that works fine.

Clicking ‘Fit to screen’ button fits maps to screen:

```
var zoom = (Math.min(this._inner.width() / this._mapWidth,
this._inner.height() / this._mapHeight) * mapZoomFudgeFactor);
this.zoomTo(zoom);
```

However font gets scaled too. Is there any way stopping it?

Comment: Couple of quick thoughts. You could apply a transform on the text and make that smaller in comparison. Or maybe keep the text as a separate element that doesn't have any transforms applied to it.

Comment: Thing is text needs to be on the same layer - it's working fine for mouse zooming in and out (text size is the same) but doesn't for Fit to screen button click.